# fosckeditor bundle - cannot configure extra plugins

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony4

I downloaded the **friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle**, added extraPlugins and their config is not being applied. My config:

```
# config/packages/fos_ck_editor.yaml
fos_ck_editor:
  default_config: my_config
  configs:
    my_config:
      toolbar: [ ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Outdent', 'Indent'] ]
      extraPlugins: 'wordcount,notification'
      wordcount:
        showWordCount: false    # disable this
        showCharCount: true     # enable this
  plugins:
    wordcount:
      path: '/bundles/fosckeditor/plugins/wordcount/'
      filename: 'plugin.js'
    notification:
      path: '/bundles/fosckeditor/plugins/notification/'
      filename: 'plugin.js'
```

[image]